# How to identify a range of data points between a minimum and a maximum in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, max, subset, cycle, minimum

My measured variable V1 follows cycles: it goes up to reach a maximum and down to reach a minimum. I call "cycle" the range of data points between 2 consecutive maxima (cycle 1 is maximum 1 - minimum 1 - maximum 2, cycle 2 is maximum 2 - minimum 2 - maximum 3). The minima and maxima of each cycle are different.

My 2 questions are:

1. how to identify the range of data points in V1 corresponding to each cycle?
2. how to extract all the minima and all the maxima in V1?

I have used `ggplot` to identify my minima and maxima using `stat_peaks()` and `stat_valleys()`. I want to find a way of doing it without plotting it, to apply it to many data frames.

[image: plot with highlighted minima and maxima]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
#I plotted my data to visualize the minima (in yellow) and maxima (in blue) with stat_peaks and stat_valleys.
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=V0, y=V1))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_peaks(color="yellow", span=61)+
  stat_valleys(color="blue", span=101)
#I used the ggplot_build function to extract the values of the highlighted peaks and valleys.
pb <- ggplot_build(plot)
```

I wanted to identify the 10 largest values in `pb` for which `colour == "yellow"` and the 10 lowest values in `pb` for which `colour == "blue"` but it does not work because `pb` is not a dataframe.

```
dput(df[1:200, c(1,2)]) 
structure(list(V0 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 
0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 
2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 
3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 
4.8, 4.9, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 
6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 
7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 
8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 
10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, 11, 
11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12, 12.1, 
12.2, 12.3, 12.4, 12.5, 12.6, 12.7, 12.8, 12.9, 13, 13.1, 13.2, 
13.3, 13.4, 13.5, 13.6, 13.7, 13.8, 13.9, 14, 14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 
14.4, 14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 
15.5, 15.6, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16, 16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 16.4, 16.5, 
16.6, 16.7, 16.8, 16.9, 17, 17.1, 17.2, 17.3, 17.4, 17.5, 17.6, 
17.7, 17.8, 17.9, 18, 18.1, 18.2, 18.3, 18.4, 18.5, 18.6, 18.7, 
18.8, 18.9, 19, 19.1, 19.2, 19.3, 19.4, 19.5, 19.6, 19.7, 19.8, 
19.9, 20), V1 = c(32.56, 31.97, 29.08, 27.34, 25.34, 22.58, 
20.93, 17.93, 14.65, 12.2, 9.88, 7, 5.52, 3.96, 3.26, 2.76, 3.23, 
3.38, 3.5, 3.67, 4.24, 7.1, 9.94, 14.58, 17.57, 21.64, 23.83, 
27.28, 29.48, 33.13, 34.37, 36.74, 37.13, 36.52, 35.87, 36, 35.49, 
33.81, 32.89, 30.47, 29.87, 27.84, 25.83, 23.31, 21.39, 18.63, 
16.42, 12.9, 10.6, 7.43, 5.95, 4.52, 3.76, 2.61, 2.94, 3.42, 
2.89, 3.38, 3.64, 4.2, 5.74, 9.48, 12.71, 17.46, 19.76, 23.93, 
27.46, 31.99, 34.07, 40.37, 46.48, 42.89, 48.33, 56.99, 47.16, 
43.53, 39.86, 37.48, 30.36, 26.01, 23.03, 20.57, 15.92, 13.87, 
11.61, 8.58, 6.52, 4.79, 3.88, 2.9, 2.94, 3.22, 3.45, 3.66, 3.89, 
6.01, 8.37, 12.83, 15.06, 18.68, 21.2, 24.12, 26.97, 28.48, 26.69, 
37.06, 40.15, 39.36, 35.73, 35.61, 35.83, 35.14, 31.55, 30.05, 
25.34, 24.24, 23.4, 21.09, 18.32, 16.04, 13.18, 10.07, 8.23, 
5.78, 4.71, 3.44, 3.48, 3.71, 3.72, 3.9, 4.56, 6.93, 9.3, 14.04, 
14.66, 16.25, 18.43, 20.76, 21.86, 23.87, 26.63, 24.85, 29.98, 
26.67, 26.99, 27.36, 25.08, 25.24, 26.48, 24.1, 22.66, 22.28, 
23.29, 21.87, 21.02, 19.53, 22.75, 22.04, 20.64, 19.05, 19.4, 
21, 18.93, 25.38, 23.59, 21.48, 21.9, 23.75, 23.38, 25.06, 25.2, 
26.38, 25.22, 28.62, 27.38, 34.16, 35.94, 34.03, 28.95, 24.33, 
24.76, 25.56, 24.96, 21.99, 23.53, 23.76, 24.5, 22.39, 23.01, 
23.42, 24, 22.65, 21.44, 22.15, 21.72, 18.46, 17.65, 15.34, 16.11, 
14.93)), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: May be worth adding the package `stat_peaks()` and `stat_valleys()` come from.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable to your data frame that labels the maxima and minima quite easily with the following line:

```
df$is_min_max <- c(FALSE, diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)) != 0, FALSE)
```

I'll explain how this works:

---

You can find out the difference between consecutive points in your data by doing

```
diff(df$V1)
```

so you can see where your data are going up or down by doing

```
as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)
```

Which will give you a 1 between two points on an upward gradient and 0 on a downward gradient. So if you do

```
diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0))
```

You will get a +1 or -1 at the points where the direction changes.

So if you do:

```
diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)) != 0
```

You will get a logical vector of the points that are local maxima and minima. Note the start and end points have been removed because we have double-diffed. Therefore we need to add a FALSE on at either end:

```
c(FALSE, diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)) != 0, FALSE)
```

So we could add this to your data frame as

```
df$is_min_max <- c(FALSE, diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)) != 0, FALSE)
```

---

You haven't included the actual data in your example, so I will show an example here using a simple sine wave:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 20, 0.1), V1 = sin(seq(1, 20, 0.1)))
plot(df$x, df$V1)
```

[image]

And now we can just find our local maxima and minima...

```r
df$is_min_max <- c(FALSE, diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)) != 0, FALSE)
```

And plot them:

```
points(df$x[df$is_min_max], df$V1[df$is_min_max], col = "red", cex = 3 )
```

[image]

Note that this will show up *every* change in direction, so if there are local "wobbles" in your data you will find maxima and minima there too. Removing these is possible but a little more complex.

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. I have adapted your answer to my needs. I would like to label the first minimum as min1, the second minimum as min2 etc and same for maximum. That way I can then define cycle1, cycle2 etc.
I am not so succesful until now
```
df$is_min <- c(0, diff(as.numeric(diff(df$V1) > 0)) == 1, 0)
df$min_rank <- ifelse(df$is_min == 1, c(1:155), 0)
df$is_max <- c(0, diff(as.numeric(diff(df$tension) > 0)) == -1, 0)
df$max_rank <- ifelse(df$is_max == 1, c(1:154), 0)
df$cycle <- ifelse(df$min_rank == min(df$min_rank) & df$max_rank > min(df$max_rank), "cycle1",NA)
```

Comment: @EmilieDeLaSylve you can get the points into another data frame by doing `maxmin <- subset(df, df$is_max_min)` and label them like this : `maxmin$label <- paste0("max_min_", seq(nrow(maxmin)))`

Comment: Thank you! As you pointed out, I have many "wobbles" in my dataset and I need to remove those because they are not true minima/maxima. I was thinking of using the average of 3 consecutive points rather than single data points. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of peaks and valleys are contained in `pb`:

The peaks are in

```
pb$data[[2]]
  xintercept yintercept label    x         y PANEL group x.label y.label shape colour size fill alpha stroke
1        7.9  0.9989413   7.9  7.9 0.9989413     1    -1     7.9  0.9989    19 yellow  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
2       14.1  0.9993094  14.1 14.1 0.9993094     1    -1    14.1  0.9993    19 yellow  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
```

The valleys are in

```
pb$data[[3]]
  xintercept yintercept label  x          y PANEL group x.label y.label shape colour size fill alpha stroke
1         11 -0.9999902    11 11 -0.9999902     1    -1      11      -1    19   blue  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
```

Note that the order of list elements may change depending on the order of ggplot function calls (*layers*).

Also note that the sample data provided by the OP is too small with respect to the spans given in calls `stat_peaks(color="yellow", span=61)` and `stat_valleys(color="blue", span=101)`, resp.

Therefore, I have used the sample data from [Allan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60434674/3817004):

```
df <- data.frame(V0 = seq(1, 20, 0.1), V1 = sin(seq(1, 20, 0.1)))
```

which highlights two peaks and one valley using OP's code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=V0, y=V1))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_peaks(color="yellow", span=61)+
  stat_valleys(color="blue", span=101)
plot
```

[image]